# Is PySCF able to print checkpoint files during a CISD calculation?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, python, high-performance-computing, pyscf, configuration-interaction

## The problem

I've described how to restart a CISD calculation in [my answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/10192/5) to the question: [Restarting an FCI calculation in PySCF](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9743/5), but this requires all iterations of the CISD calculation to finish, so that a `civec` object is returned, which is the CISD vector, which can be saved by adding `np.save('civec.npy', civec)` to the end of a PySCF input script. If a CISD calculation with a convergence tolerance of `1e-3` is completed, the resulting `civec` can be used as a starting point for a CISD calculation with a more stringent tolerance like `1e-5`.

#### However, what if the calculation with a convergence tolerance of `1e-3` crashes before it completes?

Is it possible to print `civec` after each Davidson iteration, so that if the job crashes during the 5th iteration (for example) without converging to the specified tolerance of `1e-3`, we can use the saved `civec` from the completed 4th iteration to restart the CISD calculation?

## What I've found so far

##### Checkpointing before full convergence seems possible with the MCSCF code:

I looked through all open and closed issues and pull requests on the [PySCF Git repository](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/issues?page=2&q=chk) that were suggested when I searched "chk", "checkfile", "chkfile" and "restart", and clicked on several of them that had promising titles, and the only one I think worth mentioning is [this one](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/pull/8) because it showed me that the `/mcscf/` folder has a `chkfile.py` file, but such a file is not included in the `/ci/` folder (also note that the keyword `dump_chk_ci=True` is no longer in the current release PySCF, as I mentioned in a comment on that Pull Request).

By running  `pyscf/examples/mcscf/13-load_chkfile.py`, with:

```
mci.chkfile = tmpchk.name
```

changed to:

```
mci.chkfile = `mci.chk`
```

I do get the chkfile `mci.chk` printed, and by changing:

```
mc.max_cycle_macro = 1
```

to:

```
mc.max_cycle_macro = 10
```

I am able to confirm that the `.chk` file is printed, then more output is produced, then the `.chk` file is expanded, then more output is produced, etc., suggesting that the checkpoint is being updated after each macro-iteration.

##### I'm unable to do this with the CISD code:

The `pyscf/ci` folder doesn't have a `chkfile.py`, but I did notice that `pyscf/ci/cisd.py` contains the following:

```
    def dump_chk(self, ci=None, frozen=None, mo_coeff=None, mo_occ=None):
        if not self.chkfile:
            return self

        if ci is None: ci = self.ci
        if frozen is None: frozen = self.frozen
        # "None" cannot be serialized by the chkfile module
        if frozen is None:
            frozen = 0

        ci_chk = {'e_corr': self.e_corr,
                  'ci': ci,
                  'frozen': frozen}

        if mo_coeff is not None: ci_chk['mo_coeff'] = mo_coeff
        if mo_occ is not None: ci_chk['mo_occ'] = mo_occ
        if self._nmo is not None: ci_chk['_nmo'] = self._nmo
        if self._nocc is not None: ci_chk['_nocc'] = self._nocc

        lib.chkfile.save(self.chkfile, 'cisd', ci_chk)
```

This `dump_chk` code doesn't seem to be used though. Also, the following script produces all the correct output, except ***unlike the mcscf program*** it does not produce any `.chk` file:

```
import pyscf
from pyscf import gto, scf, ao2mo, fci,ci, lib

mol = pyscf.M(atom = 'Ne 0 0 0',basis = 'cc-pvDz',verbose=5,output='out_1e-5_direct.txt')
mhf = scf.RHF(mol).run()
mci = ci.CISD(mhf).set(conv_tol=1e-5,nroots=3)
mci.chkfile = 'cisd.chk'
e, civec = mci.kernel()
```

##### Example files don't seem to involve checkpointing for CISD:

I have looked through various files in PySCF's [example suite](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/tree/master/examples), based on file names in the [CI folder](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/tree/master/examples/ci) (specifically [`00-simple_cisd.py`](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/blob/master/examples/ci/00-simple_cisd.py), [`01-density-matrix`](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/blob/master/examples/ci/01-density_matrix.py), [`20-from-fci.py`](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/blob/master/examples/ci/20-from_fci.py) and [`32-wfn_overlap.py`](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/blob/master/examples/ci/32-wfn_overlap.py)), and the [FCI folder](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/tree/master/examples/fci) ([`11-large_ci.py`](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/blob/master/examples/fci/11-large_ci.py)). Unfortunately `chk` and `check` and `dump` don't appear in any of those files! In the [MCSCF folder](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/tree/master/examples/mcscf) there's the above-mentioned [`13-load_chkfile.py`](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/blob/master/examples/mcscf/13-load_chkfile.py) and also [`13-restart.py`](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/blob/master/examples/mcscf/13-restart.py), and [`14-project_init_guess.py`](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/blob/master/examples/mcscf/14-project_init_guess.py)), the former two giving examples of printing check point files for MCSCF, but not for CISD.

##### Other files associated with checkpointing don't show a clear way to do it for CISD:

The file `pyscf/pyscf/lib/chkfile.py` has an example in the comments that contains `lib.chkfile.save('symm.chk', 'symm', ci)`, but there's nothing like `mci.kernel` in that example, for actually running a CISD calculation. The file [`pyscf/tools/chkfile_util`](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/blob/master/pyscf/tools/chkfile_util.py%60) doesn't seem to have anything related to checkpointing CISD.

## The question

Is there a native way to dump the CI vector after each Davidson iteration, when doing a CISD calculation in PySCF?

Comment: If it already works when it converges, you can probably just start with a lax threshold and tighten it consecutively. This will give you a sequence of eigenvectors in increasing accuracy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a native way to do this, e.g. an option that can be passed to CISD. The `dump_chk` option is never passed to `cisd.py`, so it clearly was not meant as an option to checkpoint the Davidson iterations.

However, this can be easily implemented by adding a line which saves the most recent input for the Davidson iterator. In file `pyscf/lib/linalg_helper.py` the iterations begin on line 416. If the following is added on line 417:

```
numpy.save(f"/path/to/checkpoint/civec_i{icyc}.npy", x0)
```

before the next line (`if fresh_start:`) then it will save a checkpoint (labelled with the iteration number) to the specified path.

I should point out that I am working on a merge request for `pyscf` which will contain (among other things) an option to save checkpoints after each iteration.